# Can auditor restore transaction dates/times/amounts?

Tags: viewkey, stealth-address, auditing

Can date/time/amount/addresses be restored with private view key? Or is just total current balance known.

What about with also having private spend key?

It would be unfortunate to be in a duress situation, and all other addresses become known.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Viewkey only shows in which TX you received something so time, date and the amount you received. It can't possibly reveal source address because it's never actually written inside the TX.

Spendkey additionally reveals whether what you received above has been spent or not and in which TX it was spent and how much. It will tell you the destination one-time key but these can't be tied to addresses. Spendkey can also be used for this in a cold setup or to export the data to auditor without actually revealing the spendkey.

None will reveal destination addresses of your funds because it's never written in a TX. Think of addresses more like instruction to sender, and not as something which itself holds the funds. Funds are always sent to brant-new one-time keys rolled at random for each TX you or someone makes.

The only way to know the destination address is to record it locally when you send and your wallet does that. If you delete the wallet file or lose the password, the information is lost forever.